# How to add dropdown to tfs check in(similar to comment text box)

Tags: tfs

I want to add a customized dropdown control while checking in some file (similar to comment text box provide as check in policy) it should come along with comment text box while we try to check in and without entering we should not be able to proceed.

Comment: Why you want to add a dropdown list, what does it used to do? This is doesn't support to customize currently.

Comment: I want to add one more control where we can map our file to some version number. So can we add one more textbox or dropdown so that we can provide additional detaals as well?

Answer (score 0):

The check in feature can't add a dropdown list like you described above.

In TFS, if you edit a file and check in it, this file is included this changeset, you don't need to map it manually. You could using the changeset number to find what has changed for this version.